# Swift Navigationbar searchbar dismiss search text on click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, searchbar

When I search in the search bar, it gives me results accordingly, but when I click outside to select my option, the search bar placeholder becomes nil and only the searched option is available. To get all the options, I have to again open search bar and press cancel which reloads the tableview to show all the option.

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ebs.png)
[Entering text in search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxd8w.png)
[After clicked on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVlJP.png)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {

let locationNames = ["Python", "C#", "Machine Learning"]

let locationImages = [UIImage(named: "hawaiiResort"), UIImage(named: "mountainExpedition"), UIImage(named: "scubaDiving")]

let locationDescription = ["Beautiful resort off the coast of Hawaii", "Exhilarating mountainous expedition through Yosemite National Park", "Awesome Scuba Diving adventure in the Gulf of Mexico"]

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var searchResult = [String]()
var searching = false
override func viewDidLoad() {
    navigationItem.title = "Courses"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
    currentPage = 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(searching){
    return searchResult.count
    }
    else{
    return 3
    }


}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if(searching)
    {
        cell.locationName.text = searchResult[indexPath.row]
        let people = locationNames.index{$0 == String(searchResult[indexPath.row])}
        cell.locationImage.image = locationImages[people ?? 0]
        cell.locationDescription.text = locationDescription[people ?? 0]
    }
    else
    {
    cell.locationImage.image = locationImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationName.text = locationNames[indexPath.row]
    cell.locationDescription.text = locationDescription[indexPath.row]
    }


    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

    vc.selectedCourse = locationNames[indexPath.row]

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
}

extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }



    searchResult = locationNames.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
    searching = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
//    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
//        searchResult = locationNames.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
//        searching = true
//        collectionView.reloadData()
//    }

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    NSLog("%@",searchBar.text ?? "");
}
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
}
```

I am new to Swift.

Comment: Could you share more of the setup code for your searchBar? I assume that `searching` is doing something else in your code. I don't think the problem is in the code you shared, since neither of those methods are called when you click outside of a search bar, and the search bar typically doesn't clear on its own.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should let the `updateSearchResults(for:)` to make the filtering/updating work, that is its only purpose.

And for the answer, maybe you are setting the `isActive` method of the `UISearchController` to `false` when tapping outside the `searchBar`, causing the text inside it to be deleted, and not allowing the search controller to update accordingly to reload all the data again.

So, a solution could be adding the `searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_)` method to reset the data source when the `searchBar` is no longer the first responder:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchResult = locationNames
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Or even better, let the `updateSearchResults(for:)` method to update the data automatically:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

    searchResult = locationNames.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```